# How many length of stay do I need to put in my arrival card in Australia?

Tags: visas, australia, study

so I'll be going to Australia by next month to study.
A few months ago I got my Australian Student visa granted until 2023 which is 4 years

However I just see the sample of arrival card it says your intended length to stay in Australia

I plan to going back to my country when I finish my Foundation studies there estimately 1 year and coming back to Australia again to continue for the next course

However I'm confused as wether to write 1 year or 4 years in my arrival card ?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you are going back in around one year. So, your intended length of stay is one year.

The arrival card is for a regular tourist, but people coming in on student visas may or may not need to fill it. If you are unsure, you can leave it blank and fill up if they ask.

In my personal experience, coming to Singapore, for work, I had to fill in the regular arrival card. Since I don't have a planned return date, I didn't fill that and it was perfectly Ok.

Comment: This answer is partially wrong, even Australian citizens must fill in the Incoming Passenger card, and can be fined for refusing to do so